# How to write Methods correctly in java - average of two numbers?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method called averageOfTwo, which is passed two int values and which returns a double value - their average. Thus if averageOfTwo is passed the int values 5 and 6, it should return 5.5.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
public double averageOfTwo(int a, int b);
{
return ((double) (a+b))/2;
}
```

However I get the following errors:

```
compilation error (line 1, column 15) : missing method body, or declare abstract
compilation error (line 3, column 3) : return outside method
```

Does this mean that my first line is incorrect somehow? I declared both a and b as int values, so I am not seeing why this is incorrect. Any tips on how to correctly format methods such as this are appreciated, as I am very new to programming.

Comment: Remove the semi-colon on the first line

Comment: And put that method inside of a class, not all by itself. `line 1...` suggests that this is the start of your file, meaning that you've got a naked method trying to exist all by itself, and that won't work, methods can't exist in that fashion. Please do read the intro chapter to most any Java text as well since you're doing a bit of guessing here.

Comment: Don't guess, read a text or tutorial.

Comment: Not guessing. I know it has to be in a class, this is one small part of an assignment. I got the rest of it correct, was just stuck on this one part. I simply forgot that the semi colon was not needed.

Comment: @Nathan That's why you should put opening curly bracket at the end of the line, instead of at the new line. It's a habit for us that every line ends with `;`, but you will never write `;{` - it really stands out.

Comment: Hi Jaroslaw - yes that makes sense when you put it that way. Thank you for the helpful tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the helpful comments I received, I now see my error was on line 1: No semicolon was needed. Instead, the code should have looked like this:

```
public double averageOfTwo(int a, int b)
{
return ((double) (a+b))/2;
}
```

With no semicolon on line 1.

Answer (score 1):

you are terminating your method as @bdkosher stated please remove the semicolong that is :-

```
public double averageOfTwo(int a, int b)
{
 return ((double) (a+b))/2;
}
```