# Finding the average using java

Tags: java

Does anyone know how to do this problem? I'm a novice programmer just trying to pass my intro to java class!

> Write a method called average that takes two doubles and returns a double that’s the average of those two numbers. For example, average(10, 20) should return 15.0 and average(5.6, 9.3) should return 7.45.

This is all I have right now but I know it's not correct:

```
public double average(double a, double b)
{
    return double a, double b / 2;
}
```

Comment: `return (a + b) / 2.0;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Methods correctly in java - average of two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439935/how-to-write-methods-correctly-in-java-average-of-two-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code should be:

```
public double average(double a, double b)
{
    return (a+b) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change your return statement like this

```
public double average(double a, double b)
{
    return (a+b)/2;    
}
```

The reason you do not need to call a + b and not double a, double b again is because you have already defined the variables a and b as doubles in the method arguments. So, you don't need to do that again and define the variables again as double whenever you use them. You can just define them once and use them like a and b separately.